# i trying to retrieve Products there is between two date but i get the following Error :

Tags: spring-boot

> Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable java.util.Date] for value '2000-04-01'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

public ListgetAllProductBetweenDate(Date date1 , Date date2){

```
List<Product> product = new ArrayList<>();
List<Product> prodretrieved = new ArrayList<>()  ;
product = productRepository.findAll();
    

for(int i=0;i <product.size();i++){
    
    if(product.get(i).getDateofintroduction().equals(date1) || product.get(i).getDateofintroduction().equals(date2)  || product.get(i).getDateofintroduction().after(date1) && product.get(i).getDateofintroduction().before(date2) ){
        
    
         
         prodretrieved.add(product.get(i));
         
}
    }
    

return prodretrieved;
```

}

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('READ')")

@RequestMapping("/Date/{dateStart}/{dateEnd}")

public List getproductbetweenDate(@PathVariable Date dateStart ,@PathVariable Date dateEnd){

return this.productService.getAllProductBetweenDate(dateStart, dateEnd) ;
}

++++++++++++ Path link++++++++++
http://localhost:8080/api/public/Date/2000-04-01/2018-07-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your path http://localhost:8080/api/public/Date/2000-04-01/2018-07-02 you are providing String types 2000-04-01 and 2018-07-02. And you are trying to getAllProductBetweenDate(dateStart, dateEnd) , dateStart and  dateEnd being Date types. Hence the error Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable java.util.Date] To solve this issue you need to convert the String from your path to Date before making the request getAllProductBetweenDate(dateStart, dateEnd)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your controller, not in the mentioned snippet.
At first glance, you probably need a `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` to your path variable.

Also, in this kind of situations consider using request param rather than path variable.